# What events make TCP in linux kernel send out packets

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

Since TCP sends packets asynchronously to the User-space i.e. the user space data is queued in the send buffer and send out when allowed by the congestion control and other algorithms, I want to know which events exactly, trigger TCP to check if it can send out more packets.

My guesses are

- When Userspace application tries to send more data
- When an ACK is received and TCP assumes it can send more data

Maybe I'm wrong about my assumptions, or maybe I'm missing out on other scenarios. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

> > When Userspace application tries to send more data

Yes. When application does the write on the socket, it informs the TCP of its intention to send out data. Based on the socket states in terms of window size, ACKs received, etc it will take its **final** decision to send it out on wire.

> > When an ACK is received and TCP assumes it can send more data

Yes. If it were re-transmitting earlier, and now ACKs acknowledge them, it will be a signal for TCP that its OK to send new segments which were hitherto not sent.

Comment: Thanks. Are these the only scenarios which trigger packets to be potentially sent out?

Comment: Re-transmission timeout is one another case.